# How to perform pattern substitution on the keys of a bash associative array

Tags: bash

I need to perform a pattern substitution on the keys of a bash associative array. Example:

```
$ declare -A aa=( [A]=0 [B]=1 [C]=2 )
```

To prefix the **values** with `foo_` one can use:

```
$ echo --${aa[@]/#/foo_}--
--foo_0 foo_1 foo_2--
```

But how to prefix the **keys**? This does not work (at least in GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release):

```
$ echo --${!aa[@]/#/foo_}-- # <- does not work
----
```

Is there a better way than the following workaround?

```
$ declare -a keys=( ${!aa[@]} )
$ echo --${keys[@]/#/foo_}--
--foo_A foo_B foo_C--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf`:

```
printf 'foo_%s\n' "${!aa[@]}"

foo_A
foo_B
foo_C
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. How can I have forgotten `printf`?

Comment: Your solution is perfect for simple substitutions like adding a prefix or a suffix. Do you have a suggestion for more complex substitutions like, for instance, replacing a `bar_` prefix by `foo_`?

Comment: Hmm replacing a prefix may not be possible in a single step. Let me do some digging.